# VSCode built-in SCSS formatter, can I set ignore a line / some lines to autoformat like what Prettier can?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, autoformat

My default VSCode setting will autoformat the my code below on save:

```
$btn-square: (
    "sm": 50px,
    "md": 100px,
    "lg": 150px,
    "xl": 200px
) !default;
```

to like:

```
$btn-square: (
    "sm": 50px,
    "md": 100px,
    "lg": 150px,
    "xl": 200px) !default;
```

I want VSCode to autoformat while saving as default, but want to keep some parts like above to skip/ignore autoformatting. Most documents/articles show how to use ignore comments for Pretier extension.

Is there a way to set comment to ingnore like Pretier for build-in SCSS autoformatter?

Comment: You are using Prettier ??

Comment: For above post, I am not using Prettier, since current VSCode has Prettier like auto-formatter feature built-in.